# How to do 'if else' judgement in SQLAlchemy RoutingSession.get_bind when using with_lockmode(master query)

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy, master-slave

I want to get a row from mysql database, then modiy some fields and commit. Before I commit, updating this row shoud be forbidden. so I use **with_lockmode('update')**. I use the
following RoutingSession and I find it use **Slave** to do this query. But I want to do this query using **Master**, what should I do in **get_bind**???

```
class RoutingSession(Session):
    def get_bind(self, mapper=None, clause=None):
        if self._flushing:

            return engines['master']
        else:
            return engines['slave']

row = session.query(SomeTable).filter(SomeTable.id = 1).with_lockmode('update').one
row.somefield = 'newcontent'
session.commit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you got this recipe from my blog post at [Django-style Database Routers in SQLAlchemy](http://techspot.zzzeek.org/2012/01/11/django-style-database-routers-in-sqlalchemy/).  If you look in the section "manual access" you'll see a recipe for when you need to explicitly point the routing session to a certain node:

```
class RoutingSession(Session):

    def get_bind(self, mapper=None, clause=None ):
        if self._name:
            return engines[self._name]
        elif mapper and issubclass(mapper.class_, OtherBase):
            return engines['other']
        elif self._flushing:
            return engines['master']
        else:
            return engines[
                    random.choice(['slave1','slave2'])
                ]

    _name = None
    def using_bind(self, name):
        s = RoutingSession()
        vars(s).update(vars(self))
        s._name = name
        return s
```

Then you just do your operation with that bind explicitly:

```
m1 = Session().using_bind("master").query(Model1).first()
```

Comment: you'll find SO works better for you if you click that checkmark next to the answer that solved your issue.